# generic routing for tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router 3 to create a generic tab. The tab is working but is not too generic and flexible as for when changing from one tab to another the route is hardcoded in the onClick event handler as I want to route it programmatically. How could I make my route more flexible and generic? Also, one issue is here for the details tab I have to provide the empty value for "to" property otherwise clicking on details tab will redirect me to commissions/1/details/details

Here is the demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/1zk95w1vwj

Here is the code

```
const Overview = () => <x-text>Overview Section</x-text>;

const Details = props => <x-text>Details Section Here</x-text>;

const Home = () => (
  <x-text>
    Home Section
    <Link to="commissions/1/details">List</Link>
  </x-text>
);

const List = () => <Link to="commissions/1/details">List</Link>;

const App = () => (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route key="list" path="list" component={List} />
    <Route key="commissions" path="commissions">
      <IndexRedirect to="list" />
      <Route key="details" path=":id/details" component={CommissionsContainer}>
        <IndexRoute component={Details} />
        <Route path="overview" component={Overview} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);



const tabItems = [
  { id: 1, name: "Overview", to: "overview" },
  { id: 2, name: "Details", to: "" }, // have to provide empty for routing to details
  { id: 3, name: "Activity", to: "overview" },
  { id: 4, name: "Feed", to: "" } 
];

const CommissionsContainer = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <FunctionalTab items={tabItems} activeItem={1} {...props} />
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CommissionsContainer;

const FunctionalTab = ({ items, handleTabKey, ...props }) => {
  console.log("props", props.router);
  return (
    <x-tab>
      <x-tab-item>
        {(items || []).map((item, idx) => (
          <Link key={idx} onClick={() => handleTabKey(item)}>
            {" "}
            {item.name} <br />
          </Link>
        ))}
        <br />
      </x-tab-item>
    </x-tab>
  );
};

const enhance = compose(
  // handler responsible for changing the tab
  withHandlers({
    handleTabKey: props => route =>
      props.router.push(`/commissions/${props.params.id}/details/${route.to}`) // this to be generic 
  })
);

export default withRouter(enhance(FunctionalTab));
```

Note: I am using react router 3

Comment: can you describe what do you mean by generic. How do you want the url to be generic in ` props.router.push` ?

Comment: By generic I mean in the routing part where it is now commissions/1/details/overview for routing to overview tab content. It works only for commission what if I want this tab in transaction module as well then it wont work

Comment: Cool. We could do it like pass a `required` `props` to the component and `push` that prop on tab change. So you have to define the url as a prop to the component you are passing.

Comment: @Panther also did you look at the tabItems object where I have provided empty value for to property if it has to be redirected to details page because if i provide details then the route will be commissions/1/details/details. Can you help me fix this ?

Comment: Can you edit in the sandbox i provided, please?

Comment: what is wrong with details/details? 

And if you want the generic why don't you use a automatic generated path for the deep linking? Every new instance of FunctionalTab receives a unique id **x-tab-counter** every other child gets an id of its own **x-tabitem-index** route will be /**x-tab-counter**/**x-tabitem-index** unique for the app.

Comment: @bluehipy Can you show that in sandbox, please?

Comment: Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/oo9yw0v6k6

Comment: @Serenity did you check it?

Comment: yeah and thanks for that but its not solving my problem. I want the route in the following form commissions/1/details, commissions/1/details/overview, commissions/1/details/activity etc

Comment: @Serenity That is not generic or I don't get the problem :)

Comment: I dont mean to say that is not generic but the routing pattern that I want is not the same.