# style react router active link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router 3 for routing. I have tried to develop a generic tab but I have no idea on how should i check if the link is active or not so I can pass it the classname as 'selected'.

Here is my code

```
const FunctionalTab = ({ items, handleTabKey, ...props }) => {
  console.log("props", props.router);
  return (
    <x-tab>
      <x-tab-item>
        {(items || []).map((item, idx) => (
          <Link key={idx} onClick={() => handleTabKey(item)}>
            {" "}
            {item.name} <br />
          </Link>
        ))}
        <br />
      </x-tab-item>
    </x-tab>
  );
};

const enhance = compose(
  // handler responsible for changing the tab
  withHandlers({
    handleTabKey: props => route =>
      props.router.push(`/commissions/${props.params.id}/details/${route.to}`) // this to be generic 
  })
);

export default withRouter(enhance(FunctionalTab));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **React Router 3**:

You can use the prop `activeClassName` of the `<Link>` component. See [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#link).

Eg:

```
 <Link
  to="/faq"
  activeClassName="selected"
 >FAQs</Link>
```

For **v4**:

You need to use `NavLink` instead of `Link` to style the link according to the matching URL. See [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink). According to the docs, you have to provide any value to the `activeClassName` prop of the `<NavLink>` component.

Eg:

```
 <NavLink
  to="/faq"
  activeClassName="selected"
 >FAQs</NavLink>
```

Comment: I did not know NavLink is in react router 3

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that you are using RRv3. Then you can directly use the `activeClassName` prop on `<Link>` component. I have updated my answer.

Comment: you can see here if i select the overview link, all the link gets the _selected class https://codesandbox.io/s/1zk95w1vwj

Comment: I could do this the following way ``` activeClassName={props.location.pathname === `/${props.label}/${props.params.id}/details${item.to}` ? '_selected' : ''}
```

Comment: The reason the class is applied on all links are because 2 each of the links point to the same route. So obviously, both will get the active class. Another reason is that the other 2 routes are nested routes. For example, if the current route is `/details/overview`, both links to `/details/` and `/details/overview/` will get the active class. You have to rearrange the routes, and use the `exact` prop of the routes to achieve any desired behavior. The answer to your question is to use the prop `activeClassName`

Comment: can you help me fix this issue, please? In both the question, the problem is related to routing pattern which is needed must.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506617/generic-routing-for-tab?noredirect=1

Comment: The issue is your architecture of routes! Hear this: You have rendered a route `details`. So now, any links whose prop contains `details` will be active. All subsequent routes like `overview` are **nested routes**, so even if route changes to them, the links to `details` will also remain active. See https://codesandbox.io/s/01z07k2x1l. Here I have provided the `exact` prop to the nested routes, so they will receive selected class only when they are clicked.